# Increase loudness of app output

Tags: ios, objective-c

Let assume user set loudness on its iphone to 5/10 value, i want to increase volume that my app outcome from 0% to 100%, where 100% is 5/10 (value that is set by user). I want that action to be made slowly increasing, for example for 20 seconds.

If i understand correct, app can't exceed value of maximum volume output that is  set by user.

Unfortunately i couldn't find a way to do that. Where should i begin to achieve that task?

I want to make an alarm.

Right now i use following logic to send push notification, that "wake up" user.

```
- (void)sendLocalPushForAlarm {
    if (IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
        [self registerForLocalNotification];
    }

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    [notification setAlertBody:NSLocalizedString(@"WAKE_UP", nil)];
    if (IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
        [notification setCategory:NotificationCategoryIdent];
    }
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only way you could maniple the loudness is when your app is running in the foreground (or rather: if you MANUALLY play the right sound using e.g. AVPlayer. this is normally not possible in the bg, so I simplified it to 'foreground only')

apart from that there is no way.

(ugly) workaround to come close maybe: have multiple notifications with multiple sound files that are recorded at a different loudness level

---

==> my vote would be no way

Comment: I use:  if ([AVAudioSession sharedInstance].category != AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback) {
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
        
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
        [self becomeFirstResponder];

Comment: ah I didn't get it right I think. you play the sound after the notification when you are in the app again then?

Comment: yes but i want to increase it from 0% to 100%, right now it started from 100% :)

Comment: `[appSoundPlayer setVolume: X];`

Comment: @Daji-Djan what is appSoundPlayer?

Comment: @Daji-Djan ok) its just not my app so i have to made tweaks in it )